# Creating Multiple Instances of One Glade Window

Tags: c, pthreads, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am running multiple threads and need to create a copy of the same window across each thread. Each one is display values relevant to what that thread is doing (calculating prime numbers in this case).

```
#include "stress.h"

//------------------------------
void windowUpdate(int *ptr) {
//------------------------------
    GtkLabel        *lbl_thread;
    GtkLabel        *lbl_total;
    GtkLabel        *lbl_latest;

    lbl_thread = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(stressBuilder, "lbl_thread"));

    char buffer[512];

    sprintf(buffer, "%i", ptr);
    gtk_label_set_text(lbl_thread, buffer);
}

//------------------------------
void windowCreate() {
//------------------------------
    //This is where the window instance code will eventually live
}


//------------------------------
void prime(int *ptr) {
//------------------------------
    int i = 3, count, c;
    const int n = INT_MAX;

   if ( n >= 1 ) {
        printf("First %d prime numbers are :\n",n);
        printf("2\n");
   }

   for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;  ) {
      for ( c = 2 ; c <= i - 1 ; c++ ) {
         if ( i%c == 0 )
            break;
      }
      if ( c == i ) {
        printf("Thread %i: %d\n", ptr, i);
        count++;
      }
      i++;
   }
}

//------------------------------
void debugMesg(int *ptr) {
//------------------------------
    printf("A thread with ID: %i was created\n", ptr);
    windowUpdate(ptr);  
    prime(ptr);

}

//------------------------------
void genThreads(GtkBuilder *builder, int threads) {
//------------------------------
    XInitThreads();
    stressBuilder = builder;    //points to the builder used in main()

//------------------------------
    GtkWidget       *winStress;     
//------------------------------

    winStress = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(stressBuilder, "win_thread"));
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(winStress);
    gtk_widget_show(winStress);

    int proc[threads];
    pthread_t prime[threads];
    char* id;

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        id = (char) i;
        proc[i] = pthread_create(&prime[i], NULL, debugMesg, (int *) id);
    }
}
```

*genThreads()* is the function where the threads are created. It's also temporarily responsible for displaying the *win_thread* window. the *windowUpdate()* function needs to be able to alter the values for the instance of the window corresponding to the thread its running on.

I'm fairly new to using threads btw, in case I've made any rookie errors.

The whole program is a bit to long to post here, so here is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/AdamFx990/CPUnix86) in case you want to look at *main()* or *stress.h* or something.

Thanks everyone :D

Comment: It's kinda usual, (if not actually enforced by the windowing framework), to create and mangage all GUI objects from one thread.   In the case where multiple windows/forms each require a thread to interact with it, it's common for the form contructor to create a thread and provide it with the form instance so that that thread can send messages/whatever to the single GUI-management thread and have it perform GUI actions on the form it's 'bound' to.

Comment: Check Gtk/Gdk [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html): "GTK+, however, is not thread safe. You should only use GTK+ and GDK from the thread gtk_init() and gtk_main() were called on. This is usually referred to as the “main thread”. Signals on GTK+ and GDK types, as well as non-signal callbacks, are emitted in the main thread.You can schedule work in the main thread safely from other threads by using gdk_threads_add_idle() and gdk_threads_add_timeout():"

Comment: In the past, there was the possibility to use gdk_threads_enter/leave and update gtk widgets but this is was very error prone and is now deprecated. Structure your code better and dispatch information to the main thread and update the UI from there.